# ¿cómo desarrollar en wordpress una pestaña para elegir imágenes de otro servidor?

Tags: php, wordpress, backbone, fileupload, wordpress-imagenes

La idea es utilizar el asistente de `WordPress` para incrustar archivos multi-media, pero que estos archivos no vengan desde la biblioteca de `WordPress` si no de otro servidor a través de la URL,

```
function add_upload_tab( $tabs ) {

    $newtab = array( 'tab_slug' => 'Nueva pestaña' );

    return array_merge( $tabs, $newtab );

}

add_filter( 'media_upload_tabs', 'add_upload_tab' );


function media_upload() {

        media_upload_header();

//Necesito importar imagenes de otro servidor al selector de imagenes de wordpress

}

function estilos_media(){

    wp_enqueue_style( 'fotos_media',  __FILE__.'/../media.css', array(), '0.1.0' );

}

add_filter( 'media_upload_tab_slug', 'media_upload' );
```

Necesito crear mi propia interface de importador de medios para crear un gestor de imágenes propio; pero que se ejecute cada vez que quieras insertar una imagen desde cualquier botón de "WordPress" para este fin.

Quiero usar url's para que se muestren las imágenes y no llenar la carpeta de la biblioteca de "WordPress".

Para esto con el código de arriba ya he conseguido abrirme hueco en el interface de "WordPress" y pegar mi código personalizado; pero no tengo ni idea gestionar el javascript de "backbone.js" y "media-views.js" que tiene por detrás "WordPress".

Necesito ayuda para gestionar este código.

Answer (score 0):

Aunque no completo tú código, ni propongo ningún código adicional, te propongo lo siguiente:

Todo depende del uso que le vayas a dar y el tiempo que quieras invertir, que por lo que veo si estás aquí consultando es que ya has invertido algo de tiempo. ¿Merece la pena invertir ese tiempo cuando Windows ya realiza la obtención de datos remota? Yo cuando quiero subir una imagen desde otro servidor, simplemente desde el gestor de Wordpress le doy click a subir desde mi ordenador y en la ventana que se abre para explorar el pc realizo lo siguiente:

[image: Obtener imagen directamente]

Si observas, en el nombre del fichero he puesto directamente la URL de la imagen, esto obtendrá la imagen de dicha URL y la subirá al gestor almacenándola en tú servidor.

Como comento, todo depende del uso que quieras darle y el tiempo que quieras invertir en la programación para realizar dicha tarea.

**EDITO: Leyendo de nuevo tu consulta, no sé si te servirá la solución que te comento debido a que no quieres almacenar la imagen en tu servidor, ¿correcto? No obstante, algo que te recomiendo independientemente de que te sirva o no la solución, almacena las imágenes que vayas a usar en tu servidor, de lo contrario podrías acabar con cientos de enlaces rotos con el paso del tiempo o incluso si has invertido en un alojamiento bueno, ralentizar la carga de la página si el servidor remoto de donde obtienes las imágenes es más lento. Otra pega, no podrás aplicar compresiones etc**

Saludos,